# Inverted vertical volume bar jquery

Tags: jquery, html5-video

Im creating a custom volume bar for a video player.  Everything works okay, but im trying to invert the direction the volume changes when the control is dragged. I think it has to do with the fact that when I calculate the position and convert that to a percentage, it is calculating that the top of my control div is 0% and the bottom is 100%.  The position and  percentage is calculated by:

```
var position = y - volume.offset().top;
percentage = 100 * position / volume.height();
```

If the bottom of the control div is clicked, console.log(position); reads out 100%.  I want it to read out 0% so when the bottom is clicked, the volume goes down and when the top is clicked it goes up (to 100%).

Heres the code

HTML

```
<video id="video">
... video sources
</video>
<div id="volumeBar"></div>
<div id="volume"></div>
```

CSS

```
#volumeBar {
    position: relative;
    height: 138px;
    width: 102px;
    background: url(/assets/vintage-vp/volume-container.png) no-repeat;
    top: -131px;
    left: 695px;
    z-index: 2;
overflow: hidden;
}

#volume {
    width: 36px;
    height: 79px;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(/assets/vintage-vp/volume.jpg) no-repeat black;
top: 116px;
    left: 735px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

jQuery

```
var volumeDrag = false;
$('#volumeBar').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    volumeDrag = true;
    video[0].muted = false;
    updateVolume(e.pageY);
});
$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if(volumeDrag) {
        volumeDrag = false;
        updateVolume(e.pageY);
    }
});
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if(volumeDrag) {
        updateVolume(e.pageY);
    }
});
var updateVolume = function(y, vol) {
    var volume = $('#volumeBar');
    var percentage;
    //if only volume have specificed
    //then direct update volume
    if(vol) {
        percentage = vol * 100;
    }
    else {
        var position = y - volume.offset().top;
        percentage = 100 * position / volume.height();
    }

    if(percentage > 100) {
        percentage = 100;
    }
    if(percentage < 0) {
        percentage = 0;
    }

    //update video volume

    video[0].volume = percentage / 100;

    //change sound icon based on volume

    var roundPixels = Math.round((video[0].volume*10))*-79;
    $('#volume').css({backgroundPosition: '0 ' +roundPixels+'px'});
```

I dont want to use jQuery UI slider for this.  I have a feeling it's just some simple logic.  Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't changing `percentage = 100 * position / volume.height();` to `percentage = 100 - (100 * position / volume.height());` do it?

Comment: Thanks!  Ive been staring at this far too long.  It works <3

Comment: No problem, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't changing:

```
percentage = 100 * position / volume.height();
```

to

```
percentage = 100 - (100 * position / volume.height());
```

do it?